# How to hide tableView header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have my tableview with search bar added in it.

```
actionsTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

I want my tableView appear with hidden header, which will appear when I scroll up.

As a reference you can have a look on Telegram/WeChat/WhatsApp messengers, they have implemented this feature.

Comment: on loading use this code-actionsTableView.tableHeaderView= nil;. when you scroll, use this -actionsTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

Comment: that is not in the header... headerview scroll with tableview so when you scroll, it will go up and in-short get hidden automatically...

Comment: You should add searchbar above the tableview instead. Then handle scrollViewDidScroll delegate to appropriately hide/show the search bar as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inside of `viewDidLoad`,

```
[self.myTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 40) animated:NO];
```

Note: Add your `UISearchBar` inside of `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your searchBar and tableView in a view(say mainView).
2. Add mainView to the view controller and assign its top(topConstant) to -40(considering its the height of search bar) , and assign the leading,trailing and bottom to view controller.
3. Now assign scrollview delegate to your class and check if tableview is scrolled on top by checking its velocity.
4. now add Animation and set topConstant to 0.